# Javascript / Vue : set background-color on specific parts of string, based on matched values in array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm struggling with making a script which sets background-color on specific parts of a string (or input in this case, but doesn't have to be...).

The solution is made with VUE, but i assume this has to be sorted out with core javascripting.

**HTML :**

```
<div class="col-sm-7">
    <input v-model.lazy="item.text" class="form-control" style="width:98%">
</div>
```

**VUE Computed :**

```
nluData() {
        return orderby(this.$store.getters.nlujson.filter(item => {
            return item.intent.toLowerCase() === this.selectedIntent
        }), ['intent', 'text'], ['asc', 'asc'])
    },
```

**Screenshot of JSON structure :**
[image]

**Screenshot of desired result (where arrows point, the word-blocks should be background-colored :**
[image]

Comment: The `recipe_search` text is supposed to be user-editable?

Comment: no... it does not have to be editable :)

Comment: Look for examples (or ready-made scripts) that do search result highlighting. Those can probably be used in this case, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use v-html and style your text as desired.

```
<span v-html="text"></span>
```

And in you component you can use the computed value as you want:

```
computed: {
     text () {
        // Code logic of your convenience 
        // Be careful of XSS attack.
        return '<b>' + this.someText + '</b>';
     }
}
```

Comment: hmm.. not a bad idea actually :) I'm gonna try this out tomorrow morning!.. Thanks so far :)